# iOS Download .doc file from URL (in Safari)

Tags: ms-office, data-transfer

One of our software suppliers normally make .doc 's downloadable via the browser (desktops). Now I'm trying to download the .doc file in Safari on iOS 9 but it just prints the document. How can I save it to my iPad and open it in the official Word app from microsoft?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to a URL that ends in .doc, it should display the document. If you then tap the screen, an option to "Open In..." should appear in the upper left. Select "Copy to Word" from the available apps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had to install the Word App and Safari shows a bar with 'open in word' on the top right of the screen. Thanks TMHahn!